# system Audio Processing Objects (sAPO) and Skype in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, audio, system, wdk

I have googled and searched a number of forums and developer websites without any success; I believe it is a  specific question that needs direct expertise or knowledge, so please read on!

BACKGROUND:

I have an audio enhancement algorithm that is implemented as a system Audio Processing Object (sAPO)  that was developed and tested successfully in Windows 7. As an APO, it applies processing to all audio stream through an end point device, including audio originating from Skype.

QUESTION:

Is it true that this is not applicable to  Windows 8.x ( 8.1 or greater)? More specifically, does sAPO processing still work for  Skype?  Does Skype disable any and all APO processing on its stream?

WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED SO FAR:

(1) I have succeeded in following the standard procedure of loading an unsigned APO from Windows 7 in Windows 8.

(2) I have tested this with Skype audio stream and that **works** as well.

HOWEVER:

(1) above, **fails in Windows 8.1** developer preview. As a result I have not been able to test (2).

Please note that I am specifically asking about Windows 8.1, in a laptop or desktop. This is not for mobile phones or tablets. Any information or links regarding this is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know this field but this doesn't look like a Stackoverflow question. Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Sorry, This is not an issue with code. This is a question regarding, Windows 8.1 and system Audio Processing Objects.

Answer (score 3):

I am also trying to update an APO which have been developed for W7/8 to the new format introduced by W8.1, however it doesn't seem like much documentation has been released yet.
What I have found so far, is that Windows 8.1 requires some new methods for discovery and control of effects to be implemented into the APO. This means that Skype would be able to discover certain APO effects and disable them if it needs to.

The new interface IAudioSystemEffects2:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Some updated code can be found in the new SwapAPO example:
[link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/slate-system-virtual-audio-f241062f)

Not much, but hopefully it can help you get going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll have a look at the links.